# Is .Contains case-sensitive in .Net?

Tags: c#

Is the string-method .Contains case-sensitive in .Net?

For example:

```
string str1 = "tEst";
string str2 = "Te"; 

Boolean bool = str1.Contains(str2);
```

Comment: in the time it took to write this question - couldn't you just have fixed the obvious error and [tried it](https://dotnetfiddle.net/7XJbYB)? or looked up [The Manual](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.contains?view=net-6.0), saying `This method performs an ordinal (case-sensitive and culture-insensitive) comparison.`?

Comment: According to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.contains?view=net-6.0#system-string-contains(system-string)) for that method - _"This method performs an ordinal (case-sensitive and culture-insensitive) comparison."_

Comment: Try out. https://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_csharp_online.php

Comment: FYI, if you use it in a EF Linq query then it will be translated to SQL and the case sensitivity will be determined by the DB which usually defaults to case insensitive.

Answer (score 0):

From Microsoft's official documentation:

> Remarks
> This method performs an ordinal (case-sensitive and culture-insensitive) comparison.

[read](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.contains?view=net-6.0#:%7E:text=string%3B%20otherwise%2C%20false.-,Remarks,method%20performs%20an%20ordinal%20(case%2Dsensitive%20and%20culture%2Dinsensitive)%20comparison.,-Applies%20to) it for more..

Answer (score 0):

Yes. By default, string comparisons are always case sensitive in the framework. The recommended way is to get case insensitivity is to use a [StringComparison](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.stringcomparison?view=net-6.0) or a [stringComparer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.stringcomparer?view=net-6.0) to specify case insensitivity.

Versions of .Net older than .Net core 2.1 lack a `.Contains` overload that takes such an argument. A workaround is to use [`.IndexOf`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.indexof?view=net-6.0) and check that it returns a index `>= 0`, since that can take a StringComparison argument.